# Using Pivot Variable in Bootstrap Procedure

Tags: bootstrap, pivot

So this question is based on Introduction to Mathematical Statistics, Hogg&Craig

In chapter4.9, it introduces bootstrap procedure and also informs that we can improve a pivot random variable using pivot random variable. So I followed exercises.

In exercise 4.9.4, if $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ is a random sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$,
  $T=\frac{\bar X-\mu}{S/\sqrt(n)}$ follows $t(n-1)$, and this is a pivot random variable since it's free of all paramters for this normal situation
(Question1. Since T follows t distribution which is not determined by $\mu$ or $\sigma$, so it's pivot random variable. Is this right?)

and we can form a confidence interval for $\mu$ in this case easily.

$P(t_{n-1, \alpha/2}<\frac{\bar X-\mu}{S/\sqrt(n)}<t_{n-1, 1-\alpha/2})=1-\alpha$

Rearranging this, $(1-\alpha)100$% confidence interval for $\mu$ is $(\bar x -t_{n-1, 1-\alpha/2}\frac{s}{\sqrt(n)},\bar x -t_{n-1, \alpha/2}\frac{s}{\sqrt(n)})$

No problem untill here.

But in exercise 4.9.5, it states that it can be improved by standardizing estimator $\hat \theta$ by an estimate of scale.

And it gives $t^\ast=\frac{\bar x^\ast-\bar x}{s^\ast/\sqrt(n)}$ where $\bar x^\ast=\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^\ast$                         and, $s^{\ast2}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(x_i^\ast-\bar x^\ast)^2$

It says that analogous to above, its confidence interval is
$(\bar x -t_{n-1, 1-\alpha/2}^\ast\frac{s}{\sqrt(n)},\bar x -t_{n-1, \alpha/2}^\ast\frac{s}{\sqrt(n)})$

Question 2. Why * ed on t, whereas s has NOT been * ed.

If it were to say that it's been analogous, shouldn't both be * ed?

Question 3. Standardizing the estimator by an estimate of scale. This skill can be still used in any other distribution other than Normal, right?  Since distribution is not really important in bootstrap procedure.

I'm pretty much sure using $s$ instead of $s^\ast$ is not a typo, since I checked it using R with an example...

Comment: Please add: What is $x^*_i$ by definition?

Comment: $x^\ast$ is a bootstraped sample. We have only 'a' sample $x$ and bootstraped sample is a $x^\ast$. So there is a n bootstraped sample $x^\ast$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. The $s$ is used to estimate the standard error of $\bar{x}$. The trick is that you don't use the exact $t$-quantile but the bootstrapped one in the CI formula you already understood.
3. Not completely, but it's a popular misconception. In fact, the useful property, why the bootstrap works, is its consistency. For "nice" distributions, the bootstrapped quantile converges to the exact quantile (without the $\;^*$). But what happens if the $x_i$ are iid Cauchy distributed? Roughly speaking, it has been shown that the bootstrap works iff a central limit theorem holds. So you can neglect the distribution as much as you would do in asymptotic statistics, but not more as there is no free lunch.

Comment: I've encountered the comment that the bootstrap works iff a central limit theorem holds. Does this refer to the process of using the sd of the bootstrap samples, or to the quantiles of a bootstrap distribution more generally?